# What does V xtor (max) mean in this equation?

Tags: voltage, switch-mode-power-supply, equation

[image: Equation]

This equation is from an [application note](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua053/slua053.pdf?ts=1660594056042&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FUC3825B) for the UC3825B.

Title asks the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vxtor appears to stand for voltage across the switching transistor.  See above for "MOSFET DC Losses".  Fig. 2 also supports this interpretation with Q1/Q2 and Rs in series with the primary winding and all connected to Vin.